# Unity Two Camera Gizmo not show

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

When I use One Camera to show the scene and put to a TargetTexture,another camera to show the RenderTexture and ui,but I find that the gizmo I use to debug not show.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear here. I can see the two camera gizmos...You should rephrase this and re-explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the image is misleading, but I have the exact same problem so I'll explain how I understand OP's question:

OP draws a gizmo (not talking about the camera gizmo, but using Gizmo.Drawx in the OnDrawGizmo method) to help him visualize some stuff.

But when he uses a second camera, the gizmo is no longer drawn in the game view (still in the scene view, as you can see on the picture).

I have the same issue with a different setup though, so I'd love to know if OP has found an answer to his problem.